# PostGIS cannot create extention:ERROR: cache lookup failed for function 1

Tags: postgis, postgresql, ubuntu

When trying to create PostGIS extension I am getting this error:

> ERROR: cache lookup failed for function 1

I am running PostgreSQL 11 on Ubuntu 16.04.
I have installed PostGIS and PostGIS scripts. I managed to create extension on one database but something caused this error so that I can't create it anymore.

Comment: Anyone any other solution? Same issue here on Ubuntu 18.04.1, postgis 2.4 and postgresql 10.8. The server has multiple databases instances running without an issue. I reinstalled postis. I reindexed all databases. I tried to run the postgis.sql manually.

Answer (score 1):

The "cache lookup failed" errors seem to be related with corrupted tables or databases. I'd try dumping the content of the database into a file and recreating and restoring the database.

Comment: I have nothing to dump since I have just created this database and its empty

Comment: Better then. Drop it and create it new again

Comment: It does not help unfortunately. I get the same error message.

Comment: Have tried to reinstall PostGIS?

Comment: I have reinstalled it. But it didn't help either. I think it lies on psql side.

Comment: Well, I guess that reinstall postgresql sounds like the obvius next step hehe. Remember to post the answer if you find a solution. Sorry I couldn't help more